# How can I extract the Geometry from a j3o file?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I created a blender file and then converted it into the j3o file.
The only way to load the 3d structure in the game is through a Spacial object:

```
Spatial towerModel = assetManager.loadModel("Textures/tower.j3o");
```

Initially the tower in the scene was composed by a simple Geometry:

```
new Geometry("Tower." + index, new Box(X_SIZE, Y_SIZE, Z_SIZE));
```

To substitute this implementation with a proper 3d tower I need to use the Gemetry object from the 3jo.

How can I extract the Geometry from the j3o file?

Answer (score 1):

The Spatial given to you from the loadModel method is most likely a Node. You'll have to traverse that node's children (and possibly grand-children) to get to the Geometry, which you will have to cast from one of the child Spatials.

I've not got the code before me right now, so I can't show you, but looking at the Javadoc it should be pretty simple (a bit of recursion should help).

Comment: I found the way to get the geometry, but once I attach it to the scene it doesn't show up; on the contrary in the "scene composer" windows I can see it. (In the blender file there's just the mesh object, I removed the camera and the lights).